# CSS Float elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I guess this may have been asked a lot of times, but I've searched accross the forum and haven't find the answer for this case.

I've some divs "container" and some divs "item" all of them floated elements, and I want each "container" below the previous one.

I know I could achieve that without using floats on the containers. But I thought that using `:after` and `clear:` would be enough.

Why this doesn't work?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {

    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25px;
    background-color: #444;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

.container {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.container:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.item {
    min-width: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `clear:left` to your `.container` rules

```
.container {
    clear:left;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rhLM6/1)**

Comment: After seeing it, seems so obvious... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearfix approach by adding the .clearfix class to your **.container** divs:

```
.clearfix:before,

.clearfix:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
}

<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

With this approach, you don't need to **float: left** your **.container**, and also,
Clearfix it's going to help you each time a **div** has floated children by making it's height variable according to its children.

Another approach would be adding **clear: left** to your **.container** but I don't recommended it since it would be an specific approach solution.